# Cannot execute workflows in Hue Load Balancer

Tags: workflow, cloudera, oozie, cloudera-cdh, hue

I'm trying to submit a workflow from the Hue Load Balancer and I'm having the following error:
"E0307: Runtime error [XML file [hdfs/path/to/workflow.xml] does not exist and app definition cannot be created because of missing config value [oozie.jobs.api.generated.xml]]"

I was researching the error and it appears that there was a Jira Case open [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-3386). I was reading all the comments but it only says that it will be fixed in oozie 5.2.0, I couldn't see any workaround for oozie 5.1.0 (the version that we currently have).

I have to mention that when we try to execute the same workflow from the Hue Server directly, I doesn't show any error and it runs fine.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: I am facing the same error. Did you find the solution?